# Schedule as many jobs as possible with two processors? Greedy Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, scheduling, intervals, greedy

I know the algorithm to schedule as many jobs as possible in the case where we have only one resource/processor:

Simply, sort the jobs in ascending order of their finish times. The greedy approach. But this was for one processor/resource.

Now we have two processors available. What would be the greedy approach for this problem?

The input is ( (s1,f1) , (s2,f2) ,.....(sn,fn)) where Sn represents start time of nth job and fn represents finish time of nth job.

Comment: The "greedy" approach is the same; just schedule jobs in ascending order of their finish times, and put the next job on a processor when it becomes available. This is not necessarily the optimal approach, though.

Comment: I'm looking for the optimal approach obviously.. can we do better than this?

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly, then. It's not clear what you mean by "as many jobs as possible." Do you have a fixed amount of time during which you need to finish as many jobs as you can? In that case, it looks like you still get the best result by sorting by time it takes to finish